# Name of outer "product" of two vectors with exponentiation instead of multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The outer product of two vectors is defined as:

$$\bf{u} \otimes \bf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} u_1\\u_2\\u_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 v_1 & u_1 v_2 & u_1v_3 \\ u_2 v_1 & u_2 v_2 & u_2 v_3 \\ u_3 v_1 & u_3 v_2 & u_3 v_3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The question is: What is the name of the following, somewhat analogous operation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} u_1\\u_2\\u_3 \end{bmatrix} \text{ ? }\begin{bmatrix} v_1&v_2&v_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_1^{v_1} & u_1^{v_2} & u_1^{v_3} \\ u_2^{v_1} & u_2^{v_2} & u_2^{v_3} \\ u_3^{v_1} & u_3^{v_2} & u_3^{v_3} \end{bmatrix} \text{ ?} $$

Comment: The origin of the operation might be important in this case.  If you found this from a research article it may be something newly defined by the authors for the specific research they're doing.  In that case there may not be a standard name for the operation which is commonly known.

Comment: I thought about including the origin, but it would make the aesthetics of the question less crisp. If you don't mind it, you can check [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/206345/67822), and you'll find the function `outer(y, seq_len(n) - 1, "^")`, which I detail after looking up what it does.